# THREE.js Custom Shader Doesn't Antialias Properly

Tags: three.js, webgl

Even if I enable `{ antialias: true }` when I initialize my renderer, the lines are not multisampled and still appear to have sharp edges. I have recreated by problem on JSFiddle that you can view [here](http://jsfiddle.net/rP5RW/).

I suspect that the problem happens because the lines are generated by the fragment shader and are not part of the geometry itself. If that's the case, is there anything I can do to make it work the way I want?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This [page may help](http://codeflow.org/entries/2013/feb/22/how-to-write-portable-webgl/#antialiasing).  The antialiasing in WebGL isn't terribly good to begin with.  I ended up using FXAA in THREE.js to get better scene quality.